# How do I get the string directly after 'me' in the string 'Help me Please' in Oracle 11G

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11G and need help in obtaining the string directly after a string keyword.  In this case I have a table called STRING_HELP with a column called STRING_NAME with the following rows:

STRING_NAME
'Help me Please';
'Will you please help me I would appreciate it';

So I'm only looking to get the strings 'Please' and 'I' from these two rows since that is what directly follows 'me' in both rows.

I have been trying to experiment using REGEXP_SUBSTRING, REGEXP_REPLACE but I haven't been able to get the string directly after the word me.  I would like two different answers please.  How do I get the string directly after me if I know everything is space delimited?  I would greatly appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you want "two different answers"?  Are there two questions?  Do you want answers with and without the assumption that words are delimited by spaces?  Something else?

Comment: Sorry I took out the other question but didn't delete that.  Assume everything will always be space delimited.  So I am looking for anything after the word 'me' and every entry will always be ' ' delmited.

Comment: Use Substr/Instr. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583577/best-way-to-extract-segments-values-from-varchar-field-in-set-based-sql/14584581#14584581

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
select regexp_replace(STRING_NAME, '^.*? me ','') from STRING_HELP
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBSTR`, `INSTR`, and `COALESCE`, but there might be a better solution:

```
SELECT  COALESCE( SUBSTR(str, 0, INSTR(str, ' ')) , str) newStr
FROM (
  SELECT LTrim(Substr(STRING_NAME,INSTR(STRING_NAME,'me')+LENGTH('me'))) str
  FROM STRING_HELP 
  ) t;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0cf12/3

Good luck.