# How to retrieve a part of a value in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, plsql

**Correction** - I only need to Pick the WORK value every result set in the column will contain comma seperated values like below..

"SICK 0.08, WORK 0.08" or "SICK 0.08,WORK 0.08"

I only need to pick WORK 0.08 from this.

I am quite new to SQL

I am using the following script to get some results;

```
select Work.Work_summary, Work.emp_id
  from Work
```

all work fine. but the first column has values like the following :

```
WORK 08.57, SICK 08.56 (Some columns)
SICK 07.80, WORK 06.80 , OT 02.00 (Some columns)
```

How can i only retrieve the column with only the WORK% value, if there is no WORK value the results shall be empty.

Comment: `WORK%` is `WORK 08.57` and  `WORK 06.80` ? Explain what you want back for your two sample datas, pls...

Comment: Do you need an answer that works for both Oracle and SQL Server? If not, you've got at least one tag that's out of place.

Comment: If Work.summary contains a value `'WORK 08.57'`, so both WORK/SICK/OT, and the numeric part, this is a bad practice. This should at least be stored in 2 (or I suspect, rather 3) columns to be properly structured...

Comment: You may use SUBSTRING, INSTRING functions to cut the string and display only what you want. It is pretty easy to use those - see help in your version of SQL. ORACLE and SQL SERVER examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583577/best-way-to-extract-segments-values-from-varchar-field-in-set-based-sql/14584581#14584581

Answer (score 0):

```
select Work_summary, emp_id 
from Work
where Work_summary like '%WORK%'
```

This will return the rows in the `Work` table where `Work_summary` column contains the word `WORK`. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I only need to pick the Work fraction of the result. every result will have WORK so this way we are effectively capturing all results..

Comment: @Dilanka So you mean you want the result to only show (for example) `WORK 08.57`, not `WORK 08.57, SICK 08.56`?

Comment: Correct you are spot on. That's exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

Contains is faster than like.

```
SELECT Work_summary, emp_id  FROM Work WHERE CONTAINS(Work_summary, 'WORK');
```

Comment: Will it be faster in all cases? Or under certain circumstance?

Comment: I am assuming that there is a full text index on the column.  If there isn't a full text index then you have to do a like statement.  But I am also assuming good database design.

Comment: Well, that is an interesting assumption given the nature of the question. There is a well known phrase about what happens when you assume.

Answer (score 0):

then use: this will give only the result where work summary contains work content.

```
select Work.Work_summary, Work.emp_id
  from Work where contains(work.Work_summary ,'work');
```

Comment: How if the result has "WORK 0.08,SICK 0.09" ? I only need to have the WORK 0.08 component in the result. Every result set will have the word WORK. ("WORK 0.08,SICK 0.08, OT 0.09" will be a possible record in this column.)

Comment: Hi if the column has the value (WORK 0.08,SICK 0.09) the you want only the value which has the work or only WORK 0.08. 
or can you tel me one more thing this is the two column value or it is single column value

Comment: Well if the column value is "WORK 0.08, SICK 0.09" I want to have WORK0.08 in my result, from somehoe manupilating the command

Comment: then its better to use substring

Answer (score 0):

```
select replace(Work_summary,",","") as work_summary
from Work
where upper(Work_summary) like '%WORK%'
```